# Count 2 different value in 1 Column

Tags: android, sqlite

One of my column has two different value, `1` and `0`. I want to count how many `1` and how many `0` is in my column and simply display it in Log but the below code is not working.

```
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " +
    "SUM(CASE WHEN my_column = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) theZero, " +
    "SUM(CASE WHEN my_column = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) theOne FROM " + MY_TABLE, null);

    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        while(c.moveToNext()){
            Log.w("THEZERO", String.valueOf(c.getInt(0)));
            Log.w("THEONE", String.valueOf(c.getInt(1)));
        }
    }
```

I have 6 data of `1` and 4 data of `0` in `my_column` and I am expecting to display:

```
THEZERO - 4
THEONE - 6
```

Comment: Did you try "SELECT SUM(my_column) FROM my_table WHERE my_column = 0"? Why are you using that query? Can you provide us what result is returning your inital query?

Comment: There's no result, I surrounded it with `Try/Catch`  No Error and No Result.

Comment: actually I just try the query in MYSQL and it works. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Hope it works. (I didn't try it).

```
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " +
                "SUM(my_column = 0) theZero, " +
                "SUM(my_column = 1) theOne FROM " + MY_TABLE, null);

if(c.moveToFirst()){
        Log.w("THEZERO", String.valueOf(c.getInt(0)));
        Log.w("THEONE", String.valueOf(c.getInt(1)));
}
```